# Getting Msg 8623, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 error on a simple select query on one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, sql-in

How to optimize a simple query that search on one table for IDes that are not a part of a set.

I created the following query

```
Select userId 
from user 
where userId not in (5000, 5001, 5002, 5003, more....)
```

Be aware that the list includes bit more than 35000 rows. I get the following database error

> Msg 8623, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions.

Some have suggested optimizing the query by using left join, but I just searching in one table so what is the alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Explicitly including an extremely large number of values (many thousands of values separated by commas) within the parentheses, in an `IN` clause can consume resources and return errors 8623 or 8632. To work around this problem, store the items in the `IN` list in a table, and use a `SELECT` subquery within an `IN` clause.

35000 clearly qualifies as *many thousands*. So, as per the documentation, you should create a table (or a temp table) to store your values, and then `left join` it as follows:

```
select u.userId 
from user u
left join mytemptable t on t.userId = u.userId
where t.userId  is null
```

You could also use `not exists`:

```
select u.userId
from user u
where not exists (select 1 from mytemptable t where t.userId = u.userId)
```

As a bonus, note that using one of the above techniques fixes a null-safety issue with your original query (as it is, if any of the values in the `IN` list is `NULL`, the `NOT IN` condition will be considered fulfilled, regardless of the value of `userId`).